How to add a footer at the bottom of the last page after all the content in a single build in reportlab
I am trying to build a reportlab playtypus application. In which there is a static header, a multi page dynamic long table a static paragraph. Finally, a footer needs to be added at the bottom of the last page. If the footer does not fit in the current page I put in a page break to put it at the  bottom of next page.
Approaches I tried were:

measure heights of all the elements then put in appropriate spacer before the footer to push it to the bottom of the page. table.wrap() doesn't work for multi page table and doesn't take into account repeat rows and splitbyrows
change page template before the paragraph so that it only occupies 80% of the page and use onPage function to print my footer. Unfortunately it works sometimes and sometimes it just doesn't.
This  seems to work for canvas but I am not sure about platypus.
If I am breaking any rules, I will make changes promptly


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
